# Why certain COGs appears more often in Humans Bacteria but not in plants Bacteria

Tags: human-biology, bioinformatics, plant-physiology

I'm doing a Bioinformatic project from the university where I  got a DB of COGS from Human & Plants Bacteria genomes and I need to find distinguishing sets in this DB and explain the biological reason behind these results. Unfurtinly my Biologi knowledge is very basic and I do not know how to explain the results so maybe someone here could help me.

Here are some of the distinguishing COGs I found and the known info about them:

```
Results for FreqItem: ['0049', '4465']
IG of FreqItem:  0.6682341035127484
COG_INFO semantic description per each COG in the itemSet if exist:
COG0049;J;INFORMATION STORAGE AND PROCESSING;Translation, ribosomal structure and biogenesis;Ribosomal protein S7;
COG4465;K;INFORMATION STORAGE AND PROCESSING;Transcription;GTP-sensing pleiotropic transcriptional regulator CodY;
Number of occurrences in Human Bacteria genomes: 63
percentage of genomes that carry it in Human Bacteria genomes: 25.0%
Number of occurrences in Plant Bacteria genomes: 4
percentage of genomes that carry it in Plant Bacteria genomes: 5.56%

Results for FreqItem: ['0049', '3833']
IG of FreqItem:  0.6952252521930348
COG_INFO semantic description per each COG in the itemSet if exist:
COG0049;J;INFORMATION STORAGE AND PROCESSING;Translation, ribosomal structure and biogenesis;Ribosomal protein S7;
COG3833;G;METABOLISM;Carbohydrate transport and metabolism;ABC-type maltose transport system, permease component;
Number of occurrences in Human Bacteria genomes: 109
percentage of genomes that carry it in Human Bacteria genomes: 43.25%
Number of occurrences in Plant Bacteria genomes: 8
percentage of genomes that carry it in Plant Bacteria genomes: 11.11%

Results for FreqItem: ['0049', '1847']
IG of FreqItem:  0.7334916442185917
COG_INFO semantic description per each COG in the itemSet if exist:
COG0049;J;INFORMATION STORAGE AND PROCESSING;Translation, ribosomal structure and biogenesis;Ribosomal protein S7;
COG1847;R;POORLY CHARACTERIZED;General function prediction only;Predicted RNA-binding protein Jag, conains KH and R3H domains;
Number of occurrences in Human Bacteria genomes: 122
percentage of genomes that carry it in Human Bacteria genomes: 48.41%
Number of occurrences in Plant Bacteria genomes: 9
percentage of genomes that carry it in Plant Bacteria genomes: 12.5%

Results for FreqItem: ['0049', '1115']
IG of FreqItem:  0.6323046964671385
COG_INFO semantic description per each COG in the itemSet if exist:
COG0049;J;INFORMATION STORAGE AND PROCESSING;Translation, ribosomal structure and biogenesis;Ribosomal protein S7;
COG1115;E;METABOLISM;Amino acid transport and metabolism;Na+/alanine symporter;
Number of occurrences in Human Bacteria genomes: 161
percentage of genomes that carry it in Human Bacteria genomes: 63.89%
Number of occurrences in Plant Bacteria genomes: 15
percentage of genomes that carry it in Plant Bacteria genomes: 20.83%

Results for FreqItem: ['4585']
IG of FreqItem:  0.3643909812004458
COG_INFO semantic description per each COG in the itemSet if exist:
COG4585;T;CELLULAR PROCESSES AND SIGNALING;Signal transduction mechanisms;Signal transduction histidine kinase;
Number of occurrences in Human Bacteria genomes: 118
percentage of genomes that carry it in Human Bacteria genomes: 46.83%
Number of occurrences in Plant Bacteria genomes: 49
percentage of genomes that carry it in Plant Bacteria genomes: 68.06%

Results for FreqItem: ['0049', '1006']
IG of FreqItem:  0.8034282332952798
COG_INFO semantic description per each COG in the itemSet if exist:
COG0049;J;INFORMATION STORAGE AND PROCESSING;Translation, ribosomal structure and biogenesis;Ribosomal protein S7;
COG1006;P;METABOLISM;Inorganic ion transport and metabolism;Multisubunit Na+/H+ antiporter, MnhC subunit;
Number of occurrences in Human Bacteria genomes: 50
percentage of genomes that carry it in Human Bacteria genomes: 19.84%
Number of occurrences in Plant Bacteria genomes: 23
percentage of genomes that carry it in Plant Bacteria genomes: 31.94%
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Bacteria in human and plants are adapted to different life conditions: different food and different environment. E.g., human gut bacteria are more likely to be anaerobic and adapted to processing organic food. So I would search in this direction (disclosure - I am not a biologist either.)

Comment: The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Unresearched questions may be subject to down-voting and closure. Please see our [homework policy](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) for more information.